# A 501c3 Church sharing a venue with a 501c7

Tags: united-states, taxes, donation, non-profit

Can a 501c3 Church that owns or leases a venue it only uses one day or two days a week allow a 501c7 social club to use the rest of the week?

The Church strongly supports the Arts and the 501c7 will be dedicated to artists and their supporters.

Would this "donation" be allowed?

The IRS also allows religious affiliation as a membership requirement for 501c7. If the 501c7 had that membership requirement would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you legally rent the place owned by your 501c3 to that organization with the status 501c7.
You shouldn't even say you support art or anything. Your only purpose must be raising funds for your organization through renting out your organization's property, and you shouldn't care what they do with it as long it is a legal activity.

Comment: I think the point is they want to let the arts social club use the venue free of charge.